# Grail's <r:script> tag as compared to <g:javascript>

Tags: javascript, grails

I've seen examples where inline Javascript in Grails has been enclosed in `<r:script>` tags for performance reasons to make it load after the page has been loaded. However, I've also seen examples where inline Javascript has been surrounded with the `<g:javascript>` tag and was wanting to know the difference between these two cases. Even in the documentation it shows that we can use the `<g:javascript>` tag for inline Javascript but we should use the `<r:script>` tag. Does this mean using the `<g:javascript>` tag for inline Javascript is bad practice? Is there the implication that the `<g:javascript>` tag for inline Javascript is discouraged because it does not put the inline JS at the end like the `<r:script>` tag does? Is there any specific case where we might have to or want to use the g tag more than the r tag?

Comment: i think its the matter of implementation ... no such aye ..performance boost for one script or another ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<r:*>` tags come from [resources plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/resources) and must be treated accordingly. (Honestly, I've never managed to get the plugin up and running even with default setup)

`<g:javascript>` tags are out-of-box Grails tags, and serve as replacement for HTML `<script/>` tags

Comment: Actually the g:javascript tag is also resource aware.

Comment: @injecteer Would you mind elabroating on "and must be treated accordingly:? Thanks.

Comment: not really... but in the documentation it's explained pretty clear, as I remember